# The number of DFA accept same language is countably infinite

Tags: infinite, dfa

I realize that the DFA is countable since the DFA for specific language is the subset of all DFAs. Just wonder how to prove that the number of DFAs accept specific language is infinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any DFA for your language. It must contain some other cycle/loop. Add a new set of states corresponding to the cycle, and allow this set of states to represent odd-numbered passes through the cycle/loop (the original states represent even passes). If necessary, add nondeterminism and use the powerset construction to turn the NFA back into a DFA.

Either way, you end up with a DFA for the same language that has more states.

Comment: All DFAs must have cycles, since they have a finite number of states but must be able to take as many transitions as are in the input string, which can be arbitrarily large. DFAs are not allowed to crash. A DFA with n states must be able to process (accept or reject) strings of length n+1, meaning some state was visited twice, meaning there is a loop. Again, all DFAs have loops/cycles. If you provide a "counterexample", I will show that it has a loop/cycle or that it is not a DFA.

Comment: If one is told that a state machine has N states that are all reachable from each other, and accepts input from an alphabet of k symbols, but knows nothing else about the machine, is there any way to compute the shortest input that would be guaranteed to hit all N*k state transitions (i.e. it would hit all state transitions of all state machines meeting the criteria)?